# How to save variables in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, variables, ckeditor, placeholder

I have to create a document editing tool using CKEditor. The document will have variables like `%account%` or `%email%` which will be replaced with values from the database upon publishing this document.

How do I save the variables as the part of the document content? Is there a plugin there to do that?

Sort of http://www.isacchi.eu/en/application/13/TinyMCE-Placeholder for CKEditor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an official plugin called [placeholder](http://ckeditor.com/addon/placeholder). The variables are editable using dialog and their values are not editable in the WYSIWYG area. Check out the [sample](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/plugins/placeholder/placeholder.html).

Comment: I know now how placeholder works. I'm looking for Any example source code example how to used assign database data can be related to the placeholder using CKEditor.